# Spark JDBC Save to HDFS Performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

Below is my problem statement,looking for suggestions

1)I have 4-5 dataframes that arte reading data from a teradata source using spark jdbc read API.
2)These 4-5 dataframes are combined into a final dataframe FinalDF that uses a shuffle partition of 1000

3)My data volume is really high ,currently each of the tasks are processing  > 2GB of data

4)Lastly i am writing the FinalDF into an ORC File in HDFS.
5)The queries i am populating into the dataframes using jdbc,i am using predicates in the jdbc api for the date ranges.

My questions are as below :

1)While it writes the DF as ORC,does it internally works like a foreachpartition.Like the Action is called for each partition while it tries to fetch the data from source via JDBC call?

2)How can i improve the process performance wise,currently some of my tasks die out due large data in the RDDs and  my stages are going for a memory spill

3)I have limitation opening too many sessions to the teradata source as there is a limit set on the source database,this stops me running multiple execotrs as i could only hold on to the limit of 300 concurrent sessions.

Comment: Maybe you can repartition data (increasing the number of partitions) after fetching it from db .

Comment: Already using a shuffle partition of 1000 so my dataframes will have 1000 partitions,If i go higher i am hitting a concurrent connections threshold from teradata source,hence was sticking to 1000

Comment: maybe you can create intermediate staging, writing whole datasets in some object storage and then read and repartition as per your requirements